# disallow powering off device within android device management

Tags: android, cosu, device-management

Is it possible to enforce the policy by which the managed device through android device management, user will not be  able to power off the device.

Comment: Have you tried enabling lock task mode?

Comment: yes, but once you long press power button it will power off.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this feature is available for Managed Samsung devices. For Core-Android this feature is generally not available at present.[Android Management Enterprise Policies](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies)